# What is this late-summer red flower?

Tags: identification

I saw this flower at the botanic gardens yesterday. What is it?

It's late summer here. It seems to have no leaves, so I guess it grows from a bulb or something similar. The total height was perhaps 15-20cm. The petals felt kinda firm and rubbery, like the leaves of a succulent.

[image: Mystery flower - side view] [image: Mystery flower - top view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has all the same qualities of a Scadoxus membranaceus. Except I can not find anywhere saying that they are known to grown in New Zealand, and the colors are much more vibrant than other images.

Comment: Ahh, I feel you must be right. This looks a lot like it: http://www.exotic-plants.de/seeds/perennials/Scadoxus-membranaceus-Scadoxus.php And here's a picture with no leaves and a brown stalk (like the one I saw): http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/haemanthus/

Comment: Actually, I think it's a Haemanthus coccineus, based on the second link I found.

Answer (score 3):

[*Haemanthus coccineus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemanthus_coccineus), is the label on mine. I have also seen a white one. They have large leaves almost a 1/2 meter long during winter.